# How to scale div using css animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to apply the scale animation when the JavaScript function is called. but i am not able to do that.
Here i have a div which contains some data inside it. initially the div is hidden and the flip function should scale the div. but the scaling is not happening through the javascript function.How can i do this?

here is what i have tried.

```
function flip1(){
    $('#category-1').delay(100).css('display', 'none');
    $('.box-1').delay(100).css('display', 'block');
    $('.box-1').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '360deg'


        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s;
        transform:scaleX(1);
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 0.3s;    
    }

    @keyframes example {
        25%  {transform:scaleX(0.060);}
        50%  {transform:scaleX(0.500);}
        75%  {transform:scaleX(0.700);}
        100% {transform:scaleX(1);}
    }     
      },200)  
    setTimeout(startSlidecat1, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: show the html or make a jsfiddle

Comment: You are mixing codes (JS & CSS)..... the syntax is very wrong... you are probably getting some JavaScript errors... debug your code (F12) and see if it makes some sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a css class with transition and on click add that class to required div

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; 
    transition: width 2s;
}

.scale-it {
    width: 300px;
}


$('#divid').addClass('scale-it');
```

*